# MPAndroidChart: unwanted spacing between XAxis and data line

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

When displaying a simple line chart with MPAndroidChart there is a vertical spacing between the XAxis line and the data line (I would expect 0-values to be drawn on the XAxis).

How can I get rid of it?

Configuration code:

```
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```

Displayed result:
[image: Line Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
YAxis yl = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
yl.setAxisMinValue(-4);//set Min value here
```

Comment: That works for line charts but not bar charts, any idea?

Comment: It didn't work on my bar chart because I called `setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);`. I removed that and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'setAxisMinValue(float)' is deprecated meanwhile.
Use this instead

```
yl.setAxisMinimum(-4f);
```